# How to force Chrome to display images on black background?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extensions, readability

If I browse to an image, I would like my web browser to display it on black (not white). How can I do that?

Comment: Principally I use Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

1. Take a look at some Chrome [Web](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ledjglfajmbclcmlohelooocdmnfdcci?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) [Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dpngnfpemfncmjhfhcbokalcacfocinc?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) apps that are available.
2. Look under the [Related](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ledjglfajmbclcmlohelooocdmnfdcci/related?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) tab there to see more app solutions you can use to reverse Chrome's look.

[image: screenshot black background]

Comment: If I understand correctly, the OP wants to change the background colour when viewing an image file. The extensions you suggested seem to be for inverting colours on all websites, so kind of different from what the OP wants.

Comment: I am not sure. @Indrek, you may be right. But I read the question differently than you, I guess.

Comment: @Indrek Looking at your link again, I'm pretty sure you are correct about my answer being not exactly on-target.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say you use Chrome exclusively, so for Firefox, you can use the [Old Default Image Style add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/old-default-image-style). It allows you to specify a custom colour for images, as well as to choose whether to show them in the centre or top-left corner.

Answer (score 0):

There is a chrome extension which allow you to change the behavior of chrome when you open an image: [Image to center](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/image-to-center/kcpejamelebpigblebnbabhndaaffjok?hl=en).

In addition to center the image in the browser instead of having it in the top-left corner, you will be able to select a solid background color of your choice or a checkerboard one like on Photoshop.

It's very useful when you are looking for a well aliased picture as there is a lot of png file with some transparency but which render well only on a white background. So you just lose the interest of having transparency and that kind of pictures are still displayed in the google result with alpha filter.